# EF7 - Custom column name for HasOne relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How do you specify a custom column name with a HasOne relationship in EF7?

Consider the following sample classes:

```
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BedroomCount { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And this fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Which leads to this DB configuration:

```
CREATE TABLE [House] (
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[AddressId] int,
[BedroomCount] int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_House] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_House_Address_AddressId] FOREIGN KEY ([AddressId]) REFERENCES [Address] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE [Address] (
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[StreetName] nvarchar(max),
[StreetNumber] nvarchar(max),
CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]));
```

How do I specify a column name other than "AddressId" on the House table?  I cannot find a method similar to HasColumnName like there is on non-navigation properties.

I'm using Entity Framework 7 RC1-Final.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Data Annotations` to configure the foreign key of your relationship.

```
public int AddressID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AddressID")]
public Address Address { get; set; }
```

This requires a property that will be used as the foreign key in your relationship. Also, note that it is recommended that you have a explicit foreign key for your relationships other than a shadow foreign key. This will prevent you to have a lot of problems when inserting/updating since you don't need to set the entire navigation property `Address` to save a `House` entity. See the problem [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

Not tested but perhaps this could work (can't find a way to install EF7 right now)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AddressID);
```

You can check here for more examples: [Foreign Key Relationships EF7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#foreign-key)

Comment: I'm not seeing the .Map() method in EF7.

Comment: Do you have to use FluentAPI? I'm trying to find a way here, guess this does't work with EF7

Comment: The combination of the `ForeignKey` attribute with the `.HasForeignKey()` method does not seem to work in EF7.

Comment: What if you only use attribute? The attribute alone should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get property first from `modelBuilder.Entity<House>().Metadata.GetProperties()` list and then set its name

```
property.Relational().ColumnName = "YouCustomId"
```